# How can I access the properties that are more than one custom type deep?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

C# Beginner here. I have this:

```
public class Item
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; } 
{

public class Property
{
   public int PropertyId { get; set; }
   public string Owner { get; set; }
}
```

How can I access the Owner string nested in there in a condition for example? Here's what I'd like:

```
foreach (var item in ListItem)
{
    if (item.Properties.Owner == "abc")
    { do something }
}
```

I tried this with no avail:

```
item.Properties.Select(s => s.Owner)
```

Comment: How you could figure this out yourself: Run your code in the debugger. Put a breakpoint on the `if` statement inside your loop. Inspect the value of `item.Properties` and see that it's a collection (and that it has `ICollection` properties, not the properties of your `Property` type). Look at the value of `item.Properties.FirstOrDefault()` and see that it is of type `Property`

Comment: Do you want to check that the owner of *any* of the properties is "abc" (hint: `if (item.Properties.Any(p => p.Owner == "abc"))`)? Of of *all*? What if the list of properties is empty?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a list of `Item` elements - then the `.Properties` property is again a **list** of `Property` objects on each `Item` - so you need to do something like this:

```
foreach (Item item in ListItem)
{
    // enumerate over the properties
    foreach (Property prop in item.Properties)
    {
        // once you're at the level of a *single* "Property" - then you can
        // get at the owner of that property 
        if (prop.Owner == "abc")
        { 
            // do something 
        }
    }
}
```